# Delete Last Row in Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I used this code to remove the last row of data from a table.

The code works in isolation but when run as part of a larger set of code it does not remove the last row.

```vb
Sub TrimJrnl()
    
    Dim wsR2 As Worksheet
    
    Set wsR2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Journal")
    
    lastrow = wsR2.ListObjects("xJrnl").Range.rows.Count
    
    rows(lastrow).Delete
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `wsR2.` in front of `rows(lastrow)`? Btw, this assumes that your table starts in row 1. Might be safer to use [`ListRow.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrow.delete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to count the rows of `ListObjects("xJrnl").DataBodyRange` so you know how many **data** rows are there (except header and summary rows).
2. You can access those data rows by `ListObjects("xJrnl").ListRows(LastRow)` and `.Delete` them.

Like Below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TrimJrnl()
    Dim wsR2 As Worksheet
    Set wsR2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Journal")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wsR2.ListObjects("xJrnl").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    
    wsR2.ListObjects("xJrnl").ListRows(LastRow).Delete
End Sub
```

A nice guide how to work with tables: [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)